# bootstrap cell mouseover background change

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Is there any way to control table cell  to highlight the cell (by changing the background color) when mouseover it?

Currently, I see table-hover but that is impacting the entire row i.e. all the cell's (in that row) background is changing.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `.table-hover` and use the following css.

```
tr > td:hover {
   /* css rules */
}
```

```css
tr > td:hover {
  background-color:red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td colspan="2">Larry the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You may not need to use `.table-bordered`

Comment: Thank You, Is there any standard class or style, that I can use directly from bootstrap, that way I can avoid customization of bootstrap.

Comment: No, there isn't any.

Comment: That is a surprise to know, how come bootstrap lagging still on this basic feature even when it is now in 5. x version. 

Are u aware of any place to request for the feature?

I am trying to post here and see https://support.gotbootstrap.com/tags

Comment: No. Does this fix your problem?

Comment: Your solution works Mohan, thank you. Being a #cleancoder I was unhappy that bootstrap was not giving this out of the box.